# Using AND in an INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am fairly new with SQL would like to understand the logic below.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table A A1 
INNER JOIN TABLE B B1 ON B1.ID = A1.ID AND A1 = 'TASK';
```

Not sure if this is a clear detail but please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: `AND A1 = 'TASK'` I believe there should be column name

Comment: it seems clear until I get to the AND not sure how that logic works and thanks @lad2025 for catching that but I want to understand how the AND is used in the INNER JOIN.

Comment: @sonnymoon `AND` means that both conditions have to be true to get "match"

Comment: You can join tables on specific columns, I think you got that far. With the `AND` in the inner join you can specify it even more. Join the tables on the columns, where `A1.Column = 'TASK'` and throw away the rest. You could just as easily move the `AND` to the `WHERE`-Clause.

Comment: Got it this is more clear now. Thanks guy!

Comment: The `A1 = 'TASK'` syntax will work if one but not both tables contains a column named "A1". This, however, reflects poor design, poor coding, or both.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table A A1
    INNER JOIN TABLE B B1 ON B1.ID = A1.ID AND A1.Column = 'TASK'
```

is the same as

```
SELECT *
FROM Table A A1
    INNER JOIN TABLE B B1 ON B1.ID = A1.ID
WHERE A1.Column = 'TASK'
```

It's even the same performance wise, it's just a different way to write the query. In very large queries it can be more readable to use an `AND` directly on an `INNER JOIN` instead of "hiding" it the in the `WHERE` part.

Comment: While this is true for an inner join, the logic is different if it's an outer join (such as a left join). If `A1.Column = 'TASK'` is in the join filter then it will resort in nulls (no match) but the line wouldn't be included at all if it were in the WHILE section.

Answer (score 6):

This wouldn't run at all

```
SELECT *
FROM Table A A1 INNER JOIN
     TABLE B B1 
     ON B1.ID = A1.ID AND A1 = 'TASK';
```

This will run because I added a column name (`SomeColumn`):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table A A1 INNER JOIN
     TABLE B B1 
     ON B1.ID = A1.ID AND A1.SomeColumn = 'TASK';
```

And is the same as this

```
SELECT *
FROM Table A A1 INNER JOIN
     TABLE B B1 
     ON B1.ID = A1.ID 
WHERE A1.SomeCoumn = 'TASK';
```

Whenever you join to a constant it is pretty much the same as adding an additional criterion to the where clause. The only reason to put it up with the join is for code clarity.

Comment: What does it mean when you say `WHERE [Table Name] = 'TASK'`?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed OP's error and edited my answer,

Answer (score 4):

**SELECT *** -- Select all the columns

**FROM TABLE A A1** -- From the table A. A1 is like a nickname you are giving table A. Instead of typing A.ColumnName (A couldbe a very long name) you just type A1.ColumnName

**INNER JOIN TABLE B B1** -- You are inner joining Table A and B. Again, B1 is just a nickname. Here is a good picture explaning joins.[image]

**ON B1.ID = A1.ID** -- This is the column that the 2 tables have in common (the relationship column) These need to contain the same data.

**AND A1 = 'TASK'** -- This is saying you are joining where A1 tablename